# How to obtain urls with descriptive content

Tags: asp.net

Asp.Net Web Forms: I need an advice about handling urls like many news site do.

Example: i've seen that some site publish an article about a soccer match and its url is something like this:

```
 http://siteAddress/soccer/big-match-Milan-Champions-league
```

In an intranet scenario (that i'm used to) i would have had a table with a numeric id and my url would have been this:
    http:/ipAddress/article.aspx?id=345

How can i obtain an url like that?

I know the urlrewrite concepts in asp.net.

Thank you!

Comment: If you know the url rewrite concepts, then what have you tried that doesn't work?  They are just doing a url rewrite to handle that nicer urls.

Comment: how can i write a rule to obtain http:/ipAddress/article.aspx?id=345 from http://siteAddress/soccer/big-match-Milan-Champions-league? With "I know the urlrewrite concepts in asp.net." i mean that i know i have to use that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScottGu's article describes several ways to solve this problem: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

On my site, I created an HttpModule (like his 2nd & 3rd approaches).  The module calls the database to lookup the article ID that matches the given URL.  If a URL is found, then the module calls `Context.RewritePath` to send the incoming request to the correct page.

If you do this, make sure to cache the database calls.  It would be best to not call the database for every incoming request.  Depending on how often you generate new content, you could pre-fetch all of the "url to article ID" mappings from your database so that you wouldn't need any database hits to rewrite the URL.